# Jquery What am I doing wrong?

Tags: jquery

i want to read out the value of List item and write it into span.
So that the lists looks like this:

- my first item (1)
- another item (2)
- next item (3)
- my first item (a)
- another item (b)
- next item (c)

But i dont find the error:

```
<div id="Listgroup">
    <ul id="list1"> 
      <li><a href="" value="1">my first item<span></span></a></li>
      <li><a href="" value="2">another item<span></span></a></li>
      <li><a href="" value="3">next item<span></span></a></li>
    </ul>
<br>
    <ul id="list2"> 
      <li><a href="" value="a">my first item<span></span></a></li>
      <li><a href="" value="b">another item<span></span></a></li>
      <li><a href="" value="c">next item<span></span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
$(function(){
$("li a").each(function(idx, item){
    $("span", "li a[value|=' + $(this).attr('value') + ']")
        .html(" (" + $(this).attr('value') + ")");
});
});
</script>
```

please help

Thank you

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: [tag:list] *specifically* says in its description that it is NOT for HTML lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your quotation marks don't match the string quotation marks, so its classing `' + $(this).attr('value') + '` as a string, rather than `$(this).attr('value')` as an object

```
$("span", "li a[value|=" + $(this).attr('value') + "]")
```

Also, you don't need to find the value like that. You already know what `this` is, so you can just [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) the `span` from there.

Furthermore, the anchor element has no `value` attribute, making this HTML invalid. You should change it to `data-value` which would make it compliant with HTML5:

```
$(function(){
$("li a").each(function(idx, item){        
    $(this).find("span").html(" (" + $(this).data("value") + ") ");    
});
});
```

[**-- SEE DEMO --**](http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/86Tc6/3/)

Comment: Hello Newbie, welcome to StackOverflow. If Curt's answer helped you, please be nice and mark his answer as "right" answer with the hook. Thanks.

Comment: @jfriend00 Does `this.value` and `.val()` work for anchor elements?

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  I guess the other alternative would be to use `this.getAttribute("value")`.  Or use the HTML5 standard and use `data-value="a"` as the attribute and then you can use `.data("value")` to fetch it.  I didn't realize it was an `<a>` link at the time I wrote my first comment.

Comment: @jfriend00 I didn't realise you could use `.data("value")` for `data-value`! Cheers!

Comment: An `<a>` element has no value, as stated use data attributes.

Comment: Hello Curt, thanks again for the fast and right answer. ;-) I am new on stackoverflow.com. i want to write a linebrake with riturn, and i did not know that this send the comment.